# Testing react component methods with HOC

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

As in the topic I would like to test react component methods that have HOC.

Usually I did it this way:

```js
describe('component method', () => {
  it('returns with null or undefined value', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
    expect(wrapper.instance().methodName());
  });
});
```

but right now I have component that needs store so I am trying to do it this way:

```js
describe('component method', () => {
  it('returns with null or undefined value', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component store={store} />);
    expect(wrapper.instance().methodName());
  });
});
```

of course store is defined:

```js
const mockStore = configureMockStore();
let store;
```

but I get error

```
TypeError: wrapper.instance().methodName is not a function
```

Could it be because my component is wrapped like this?

```js
export default withSocket(Component);
```

If yes how can I solve it?

Comment: Would mocking the HOC and just testing the component be sufficient? Or are you trying to test the HOC and component together?

Comment: I just want to test component, I do not need to test HOC, the problem is that the component has loading state and uses socket to get values from backend so when it doesn't get values from backend it will not change loading state to false so it will not render any elements

Comment: I think you can either mock the `withSocket` or export the component directly to test since `withSocket` should be tested in a somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want to test the component, I would recommend mocking the HOC.

In order to do so, use `jest.mock` and provide a mock implementation

Inside your test file do:

```js
jest.mock('./path-to-the-hoc', () => function withSocket(Component) {
  // edit: should be inlined here to prevent this error:
  // > The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.
  const { forwardRef } = require('react');
  

  const MockWithSocket = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        // if you need to test instance methods, forward a ref here
        ref={ref}
        // additionally you can add props that the HOC would add here
        foo="bar"
       />
    );
  });

  return MockWithSocket;
});

describe('blah', () => {
  it('blah', () => {
    // render the component as you normally would,
    // the mock above works the module level and will swap
    // the real implementation for your mock above
  });
});
```

---

Edit: React allows you to access instance methods via refs. HOCs add an extra layer of abstraction and it'll break React's way to get to the instance so in order to allow access, you have to use `forwardRef`

Comment: hmm I get `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mockWithSocket' before initialization`

Comment: Oh my bad. I guess I would just inline it then. I'll update my answer

Comment: I changed that but it looks like I cannot test functions inside it... I tried to add `const wrapper = shallow(<Component />)` and `expect(wrapper.instance().methodName())` but it doesn't work, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'methodName' of null`

Comment: ah to get to the methods inside, you'd probably need to forward the ref. I'll update the answer again

Comment: Side Note: @Sowam if mocking HOCs seems hard, it's because it is. The React team replaced the HOC pattern with react hooks and they are strongly recommending hooks over class components [See here](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/3308#issuecomment-705707032)

Comment: I got this weird error now `The target 'phcikntpzafpxootrenq' could not be identified in the dom, tip: check spelling` ... I don't even have this element in DOM. I know but this is really big project so refactoring every component to functional would take a lot of time

Comment: I got `The module factory of \`jest.mock()\` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.`

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution...

```
const mockStore = configureMockStore({});
const store = mockStore();

let wrapper;
beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Component store={store} />)
        .dive()
        .dive();
});

describe("method", () => {
    it("returns correctly when prop is null or undefined", () => {
        expect(wrapper.instance().methodName(null)).toBe("Test");
        expect(wrapper.instance().methodName(undefined)).toBe("Test");
    });
});
```

I just tried to use `dive()` but it didn't work... it started when I added second `dive()` but I still cannot understand what does it change. Is it because I have HOC around this component so I have to "dive" inside to get it or what?